# How Parse save eventually work?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

When there is **no internet connection** I can use **save eventually to store data locally**.But after the **internet connection restored**, can the application **upload the data automatically?** if not, how can I upload it to cloud? Here is my code. thx in advance.

```
        //parse
        var moment2:PFObject = PFObject(className: "e_Moments")
        moment2["Location"] = locationTextField.text
        moment2["FullName"] = nameTextField.text
        moment2["Company"] = typeTextField.text
        moment2["thoughts"] = thoughtsTextField.text

        let image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image)
        let imageFile = PFFile(data: image)
        moment2["Image"] = imageFile

        moment2.saveEventually()  //save offline
        moment2.saveInBackground()//save object
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes the data should be uploaded automatically but there is no specific time when this will happen.  That is, it will happen after the internet connection is restored at some point.

The data will persist locally even if you closedown your application and when you relaunch it, then the save operation will try again to save the data to parse.

If you are saving more than 10 MB with saveeventually, then read the following Class reference for a constaint about saveeventually and old save operations in the cache.  [PFObject Class Reference](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/saveEventually)

Comment: Good answer. I think it's also worth noting that success blocks don't persist after the first try. So if you are incorporating something to do in the success block of saveEventually be sure it's going to execute.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to reproduce this? In Android I want to be able to do the same thing. It's about registering and unregistering your device id in my backend but whenever the user logs out while offline this fails.

Comment: Sorry Jonas, I do not have any experience with Android.  Try creating a new question for that.  Good luck!